# Passing paths with spaces as arguments

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, quoting, arguments

I am having difficulty in passing some string variables having spaces in them as arguments to a program.
For debugging and showing the arguments being passed, I created a demo Python script -:

```
##### show_args.py #####

import sys

def main():
    # Display the arguments passed to the script
    print "Number of arguments =", len(sys.argv)
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, the script demonstrating the problem -:

```
path_with_spaces="$HOME/blah blah"
arg_list="$path_with_spaces/abc $path_with_spaces/xyz"

python show_args.py $arg_list
```

Output -:

```
Number of arguments = 5
show_args.py
/home/anmol/blah
blah/abc
/home/anmol/blah
blah/xyz
```

What I actually want is this -:

```
path_with_spaces="$HOME/blah blah"

python show_args.py "$path_with_spaces/abc" "$path_with_spaces/xyz"
```

Output -:

```
Number of arguments = 3
show_args.py
/home/anmol/blah blah/abc
/home/anmol/blah blah/xyz
```

To confirm that the problem was occurring only for paths with spaces in them, I created the following script -:

```
path_without_spaces="$HOME/blah"
arg_list="$path_without_spaces/abc $path_without_spaces/xyz"

python show_args.py $arg_list
```

Output -:

```
Number of arguments = 3
show_args.py
/home/anmol/blah/abc
/home/anmol/blah/xyz
```

While searching for the solutions to this problem, I encountered [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/42552), according to which the correct way is to put the arguments in an array variable rather than a string variable.
The script showing this new approach -:

```
path_with_spaces="$HOME/blah blah"
arg_list=("$path_with_spaces/abc" "$path_with_spaces/xyz")

python show_args.py "${arg_list[@]}"
```

Output -:

```
Number of arguments = 3
show_args.py
/home/anmol/blah blah/abc
/home/anmol/blah blah/xyz
```

Although, this solution is working correctly, **I still want to know if there is a way with which we can accomplish the same thing using a string variable rather an array variable.**

My system configuration -:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Bash 4.3.11
- Gnome Terminal 3.6.2

Comment: there could be several strategies. one ugly back i used to do in bash was replacing spaces for _ or "x". use your imagination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
path_with_spaces="$HOME/blah blah"
arg_list="$path_with_spaces/abc $path_with_spaces/xyz"

python show_args.py $arg_list
```

You're using a scalar/string variable and using the *split+glob* operator (leaving that variable unquoted) to split the content of that variable and generate the arguments to pass to `python`.

The *split* part of the *split+glob* operator splits on the characters stored in the `$IFS` special parameter.

Here, you could disable the *glob* part and split on a character not found in your paths. For instance, if *newline* is not found in the paths:

```
path_with_spaces="$HOME/blah blah"
arg_list="$path_with_spaces/abc
$path_with_spaces/xyz"
IFS="
"
set -f # disable glob.
python show_args.py $arg_list
```

You could also use shell quoting and use `eval` to have the shell interpret those quotes (here using `bash`-specific features):

```
printf -v arg_list '%q ' "$path_with_spaces/abc" \
                         "$path_with_spaces/xyz"

eval "python show_args.py $arg_list"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use the default path separator to separate paths. There are two kinds of characters which are illegal in a path-name:

- the `\0NUL` character
- the `/` path separator

As it happens, you can separate path-names on the separator with the shell's *Internal Field Separator* `$IFS` special parameter. When two or more separators occur in sequence, the resulting component will be a `\0NUL` valued argument - which cannot be a path-name.

To work you must root all paths directly *(and so rule out a root `//`)*, and you must ensure you have canonical paths - or at the least that all `//*` have been squeezed to a single occurrence per *(dots won't hurt - or help)*. Once you have done so:

---

```
paths='/path/one//path/t w o//p a t h/t h r e e/'
set -f --; IFS=/
for p in ${paths#/}$IFS
do  printf ${p:+/}%s\\n "$*"
    set -- ${p:+"$@"/$p}
done
```

---

```
/path/one
/path/t w o
/p a t h/t h r e e
```

---

You can get a canonical path in `$PWD` w/ `cd`.

---

```
cd -- /some//../screwy/../path/to///destination
printf %s\\n "$PWD"
```

---

```
/path/to/destination
```

---

If you use the `-P` switch `cd` will ensure an absolute, physical path to the current working directory is set to `$PWD`. Else with `-L` or by default `cd` will maintain any indirections implied by previous changes to symlinked directories as your shell session progresses.

And so you can most reliably collect the names in a tree by walking it.